# T-SQL Looking for the most concise way to summarize a starting and ending date range

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Really long story short, I have two datetime fields in a table that I am loading into variables @DateFrom and @DateTo, and I need to "explain" what sort of range they cover in text for presentation on the screen.  Although the fields are datetime, the time component will be ignored.  I am also declaring @Current as a datetime to hold the result of getDate(), in case I need to strip off the time before comparing.

As this sort of thing isn't terribly uncommon, I am hoping someone has done it before.

Some examples (I will use today's date of April 6, 2015 for @Current):

```
If @DateFrom is April 6, 2015, and @DateTo is also April 6, 2015, return "Today"
If @DateFrom is April 5, 2015, and @DateTo is also April 5, 2015, return "Yesterday"
If @DateFrom is April 2, 2015, and @DateTo is April 6, 2015, return "Last 4 days"
If @DateFrom is March 29, 2015, and @DateTo is April 4, 2015, return "Last week"
    (March 29 is Sunday, and April 4 is Saturday).
If @DateFrom is April 1, 2015, and @DateTo is April 30, 2015, return "This month"
If @DateFrom is March 1, 2015, and @DateTo is March 31, 2015, return "Last month"
If @DateFrom is March 28, 2015, and @DateTo is April 5, 2015, 
    return "From March 28, 2015 To April 5, 2015" 
    (because it doesn't fit any of the standard date ranges).
```

I am hoping someone has published the code for a function or stored procedure to do this or very similar somewhere, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why isn't `@Current` just a `DATE`, since "the time component will be ignored"?

Comment: Good point, whatever makes the final code as clean and easy as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit ugly, but probably the best T-SQL can do:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATE, @DateTo DATE
DECLARE @Current DATE = GETDATE() 

DECLARE @BeginningOfLastWeek DATE = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE())-1,-1)
DECLARE @EndOfLastWeek DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 6, @BeginningOfLastWeek)

DECLARE @BeginningOfCurrentMonth DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Current), 0)
DECLARE @EndOfCurrentMonth DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @BeginningOfCurrentMonth))

DECLARE @BeginningOfLastMonth DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Current)-1, 0)
DECLARE @EndOfLastMonth DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @BeginningOfLastMonth))

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN @DateFrom = @Current AND @DateTo = @Current THEN 'Today' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = DATEADD(d, -1, @Current) AND @DateTo = @DateFrom THEN 'Yesterday' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = DATEADD(d, -4, @Current) AND @DateTo = @Current THEN 'Last 4 Days' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = @BeginningOfLastWeek AND @DateTo = @EndOfLastWeek THEN 'Last week' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = @BeginningOfCurrentMonth AND @DateTo = @EndOfCurrentMonth THEN 'This month' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = @BeginningOfLastMonth AND @DateTo = @EndOfLastMonth THEN 'Last month' 
        ELSE 'From ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @DateFrom, 107) + ' To ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @DateTo, 107)
    END
```

Comment: See below for my complete solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a function or sproc that's already built, but there is something on Pinal Dave's site where you can copy-paste and have 80% of your function ready: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/29/sql-server-few-useful-datetime-functions-to-find-specific-dates/

Comment: I have used this code from Pinal Dave before, to do exactly the opposite of what I am doing here.  His code is all about going from a qualified date selection (i.e. "Yesterday") to actual date values, whereas I am taking the actual date values and trying to summarize them as best as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @thepirat000, I have used the bulk of your code in my final solution, which I put below.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN @DateFrom = @Current AND @DateTo = @Current THEN 'Today' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = DATEADD(d, -1, @Current) AND @DateTo = @DateFrom THEN 'Yesterday' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = @BeginningOfLastWeek AND @DateTo = @EndOfLastWeek THEN 'Last week' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = @BeginningOfCurrentMonth AND @DateTo = @EndOfCurrentMonth THEN 'This month' 
        WHEN @DateFrom = @BeginningOfLastMonth AND @DateTo = @EndOfLastMonth THEN 'Last month' 
        WHEN DATEPART(m,@DateFrom) = DATEPART(m,@DateTo) AND DATEPART(d,@DateFrom) = 1 
            AND DATEPART(d,@DateTo) = datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1-day(@DateFrom), @DateFrom), dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1-day(@DateFrom), @DateFrom))) 
            THEN DATENAME(MM, @DateFrom) -- the name of the month
        WHEN DATEPART(dy,@DateFrom) = DATEPART(dy,@DateTo) AND @DateTo = @Current THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(y,@DateFrom,@DateTo) AS varchar(2)) + ' years ago'
        WHEN DATEPART(d,@DateFrom) = DATEPART(d,@DateTo) AND @DateTo = @Current THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(m,@DateFrom,@DateTo) AS varchar(2)) + ' months ago'
        WHEN DATEPART(dw,@DateFrom) = DATEPART(dw,@DateTo) AND @DateTo = @Current THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(wk,@DateFrom,@DateTo) AS varchar(2)) + ' weeks ago'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,@DateFrom,@DateTo) < 30 AND @DateTo = @Current THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(d,@DateFrom,@DateTo) AS varchar(2)) + ' days ago'
        ELSE 'From ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @DateFrom, 107) + ' To ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @DateTo, 107)
    END
```

It doesn't handle month/months nicely, but it's close enough for what I need it to do.

Comment: If anyone looks at this for a solution, change `THEN DATENAME(MM, @DateFrom)` above to `THEN DATENAME(MM, @DateFrom) + ' ' + DATENAME(YYYY, @DateFrom)` to include the year, as that's kinda important.